# Playing audio with AVAudio Record from SQLite BLOB

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, avaudioplayer

I have a UIButton inside of a UITableViewCell hooked up to a method to play an AVAudio file like this:

```
cell.playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(useSelectedFile:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the useSelectedFile method looks like this:

```
-(void) useSelectedFile:(id)sender{

    int tag = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
    NSDictionary *audioFileInformation = [audioCellsArray objectAtIndex:tag];
    NSData *selectedAudioFile = [audioFileInformation objectForKey:@"Data"];
    NSError *error;

    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
    [selectedAudioFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]; 


    _audioPlayerForButton = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    else
        [_audioPlayerForButton play];

}
```

I can record files and save them in the database and pull the data out fine, however I can't play them. With the current code I get: Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)

and when I tried just using:

```
_audioPlayerForButton = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:selectedAudioFile error:&error];
```

I would get this error when hitting the play button: Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Inspecting the file I write to disk from the simulator it seems to be corrupt maybe? the file system doesn't show it as an audio file like normal .caf files (black with the music note) but as a little white file with the QuickTime symbol on it that QuickTime won't play.

I tried using macerror statuscode on the command line but it just returns "unknown error".

Anyone have any ideas or tips on how to resolve this and get my files playing?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was right, after comparing the files more I could clearly see the data was different so I changed from storing the files as a `BLOB` to `TEXT` and just encoded them using a *base64 class* from here: [iPhone SDK base64 encode / decode](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php)